# Testing for orthogonal columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am reading about matrices with orthogonal columns (not necessarily an orthogonal matrix). [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Matrix_properties):

> It might be tempting to suppose a matrix with orthogonal (not
>   orthonormal) columns would be called an orthogonal matrix, but such
>   matrices have no special interest and no special name; they only
>   satisfy $M^TM = D$, with $D$ a diagonal matrix.

Is it also true that $MM^T = D$ implies that $M$ has orthogonal columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $MM^T = D$ only implies that $M$ has orthogonal rows.

For example
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ -6 & 3\end{pmatrix}
$$
yields
$$
MM^T = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 45\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the rows are indeed orthogonal. However
$$
M^T M = \begin{pmatrix} 37 & -16 \\ -16 & 13\end{pmatrix},
$$
so the columns are not orthogonal.